# How to get get name of the most recent (by creation time) directory in a Windows script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need some help in getting the name of the most recent directory in a Windows script.

I have found some information on getting the most recent file which works but I cannot get this to work on directories.

For example, here is my directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 usrpm Domain Users 0 Jun 29 10:34 _200903_V20
drwxr-xr-x 2 usrpm Domain Users 0 Jun 29 10:35 _200904_V21
drwxr-xr-x 2 usrpm Domain Users 0 Jun 29 10:36 _200905_V22
drwxr-xr-x 2 usrpm Domain Users 0 Jun 29 10:38 _200906_V23
```

I need my script to return me the most recent directory (V23).  I will then cd into that directory and copy a file out of it.

Comment: Do you really mean "DOS", or do you mean "Windows command shell", and if the latter, do you mean specific to 16-bit, 32-bit, or 64-bit?  I don't know whether the 64-bit is different from 32-bit, but there is syntax that was added to 32-bit CMD.EXE that 16-bit COMMAND.COM didn't support.  Not to mention that there are third party command shells out there...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](http://www.ericphelps.com/batch/samples/recent.txt) is a link to two scripts that find the most recent file.  I think the second one already does exactly what you want, but you can modify one of them to do what you need, I'm pretty sure.  I just googled ["find most recent file dos batch file"](http://www.google.com/search?q=find+most+recent+file+dos+batch+file) and found it immediately.

[Source link](http://www.ericphelps.com/batch/samples/samples.htm).

Edited to add a script that works with directories:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /b *.*') do set recent=%%x
echo %recent%
```

Output:

```
C:\> recent.bat
recent.bat
C:\> mkdir newdir

C:\> recent.bat
newdir
```

Looks like it works here.

Comment: Thanks Carl, I found this link earlier today and it works perfectly to find the most recent "file".  But I have been trying to edit it to find the most recent "directory" and have not been able to get it to work.

Comment: Awesome thanks Carl, after I removed the /a-d this script worked as well.  Thanks again!

Comment: On Windows 7 the above still gives me the latest file not the latest folder

Comment: with `/a-d` it returns files, with `/ad` it returns folders and without one of them, it returns both files and folders.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`dir /ad /o-d /b`) do (
    set LETESTDIR=%%i
    goto cont
)

:cont
echo %LETESTDIR%
```