# Get the latest created folder path in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there any way I can get the latest folder name created in a specified path?

I have the below path:

```
C:\Test_bat\Archive
```

Within this path folder are dynamically created and on the run I want to get in to this folder at some point for renaming one of the file which gets created.

```
C:\Test_bat\Archive\NewFolder
```

Pseudo code of my running bat, test.bat:

```
set datestr= %date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%
set currtime=%time: =0%
set timestr=%currtime:~0,2%%currtime:~3,2%%currtime:~6,2%
set currdatetime=%datestr%_%timestr%
rename "C:\Test_bat\Archive\NewFolder\log.txt" "Log_%currdatetime%.txt"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what i got , took a refrence from below SO question :

[GetNameOfRecentDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724278/help-writing-dos-script-to-get-get-name-of-the-most-recent-directory-time-creat)

> Mine implementation :

```
set datestr= %date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%
set currtime=%time: =0%
set timestr=%currtime:~0,2%%currtime:~3,2%%currtime:~6,2%
set currdatetime=%datestr%_%timestr%

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "C:\Test_bat\Archive" /b /ad-h /t:c /o-d') DO (
SET a=%%i
GOTO :found
)
goto :eof
:found
rename "C:\Test_bat\Archive\%a%\ExecutionLog.txt" "Log_%currdatetime%.txt"
```